# Merging Django querysets of differing sizes causing date missmatch in graph view with date value

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I've got 2 querysets, each filtertering by transactionType over the same date range, only problem is, the queryset are returning differnet sizes as some of the dates dont match with the applied filter, so instead of it returning 0 it returns 'empty' ( or so i believe )

```
current_date = datetime.today()

months_ago = 6

six_month_previous_date = current_date - timedelta(days=(months_ago * 365 / 12))

aggregatedSales = Transactionlog.objects.using('database').filter(transactiondate__gte=six_month_previous_date).filter(
    transactiontype=1).values('transactiondate').annotate(sales_by_month=Count('transactiondate'))

aggregatedRefunds = Transactionlog.objects.using('database').filter(
    transactiondate__gte=six_month_previous_date).exclude(transactiontype=1).values('transactiondate').annotate(
    ref_by_month=Count('transactiondate'))

transaction_Values_list = list(chain(aggregatedRefunds, aggregatedSales ))

transaction_Values_rules = defaultdict(dict)

for dic in transaction_Values_list:
    transaction_Values_rules[dic['transactiondate']].update(dic)
```

My Issue being that when these 2 querysets are diplayed in a graph the differing length cause a miss match in the dates - im using Chart.js to render the charts on my template using the follwing -

```
    (function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var fixedLineChart = $('#fixed-line-chart');
    var fixedLineChartJS = new Chart(fixedLineChart, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: [{% for dates in aggregated %}'{{ dates.transactiondate|date:'Y-m-d H:i:s' }}',{% endfor %}],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Sales',
          data: [{% for sales in aggregated %}'{{ sales.sales_by_month }},{% endfor %}],
          borderColor: chartColorGreen,
          backgroundColor: rgbToRgba(chartColorGreen, '.25'),
          pointBackgroundColor: chartColorGreen,
          pointBorderColor: rgbToRgba(chartColorGreen, '.25'),
          lineTension: 0,
          fill: 'origin',
        },{
          label: 'Refunds',
          data: [{% for ref in aggregated %}'{{ ref.ref_by_month }},{% endfor %}],
          borderColor: chartColorPink,
          backgroundColor: rgbToRgba(chartColorPink, '.25'),
          pointBackgroundColor: chartColorPink,
          pointBorderColor: rgbToRgba(chartColorPink, '.25'),
          lineTension: 0,
          fill: 'origin',
        }]
      },
      options: {
        hover: {
          mode: 'index',
          intersect: false
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
      }
    });
```

is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was a more simple task that i thought, simply iterate over the dict items checking if the key exists and if not - create a empty value -

```
    for i in transaction_Values_rules.values():
    if 'ref_by_month' in i:
        pass
    else:
        i['ref_by_month'] = '0'
```